# Trouble understanding how to set my login activity to the launcher activity in the Android manifest

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I want to change my manifest so that the Login Activity is the first activity to start on the phone. The login activity checks the sharedpreferences to see if a user has login info saved. If they do it logs them in. Im pretty sure I need an intent-filter in login activity with `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` but I dont get what I should put for the action. 

 Heres my manifest

```
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.incubatorcle.dinahealth.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UserOnboardActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_onboard" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MainActivity need to look like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.yourpacgagename.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Your Login activity need to look like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

- ACTION_MAIN action indicates this is the main entry point and does
  not expect any intent data.
- CATEGORY_LAUNCHER category indicates
  that this activity's icon should be placed in the system's app
  launcher.

Answer (score 0):

As your question is answered by @wariaten

Here is another way to do the login check

Add a third activity (where you check the `SharedPreferences` and launch the `LoginActivity` or the `HomeActivity`) and set it as the launcher as suggested by @wariaten